# log2 in R: How to calculate the exponent and mantissa

Tags: r, matlab, logarithm

Does anyone know how to carry out the same MATLAB function `[F,E] = log2(X)` in R?

> [F,E] = log2(X) returns arrays F and E such that X=F*2^E. The values
>   in F are typically in the range 0.5 <= abs(F) < 1.

See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/log2.html

> For example in MATLAB,
>
> [F,E] = log2(15)
>
> F =
>
> ```
> 0.9375
> ```
>
> E =
>
> ```
>  4
> ```

Thus,

> F*2^E = 15

Comment: Please give a [mcve]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to calculate them manually. I don't think there's a builtin to extract them. Try this:

```
x<-15
E <- ifelse(x == 0, 0, floor(log2(abs(x)))+1 )
F<-x/2^E
```

Edit: Made the change for the case of x==0.

Comment: @user7283235, You will need to be careful with this because I'm not sure whether this is exactly right for negative numbers. Specifically it may go wrong for -2^N, so you should check it.

Comment: @Rohit Is the following proper? `E <- ifelse(x == 0, 0, floor(log2(abs(x)))+1 )`, in case `x ==0.`

Comment: @user7283235 Yes, I believe so. I forgot about the `x=0` case.

Comment: @MauritsEvers, That is identical to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking but `log2` gives you the logarithm base 2 in R. For example

```
log2(2);
#[1] 1

log2(2^10)
#[1] 10

2^(log2(10))
#[1] 10
```

See `?log` for details.

Comment: Thanks. No, I'm asking how to calculate F and E. Please see my edited example.

Comment: @user7283235 Ah yes, I see. In that case, Rohit's answer seems to be what you're after. Easy to wrap in a convenience function like `log2_EF <- function(x) return(c(E <- floor(log2(x) + 1), x / 2^E))`.